# Problem of Android Studio Java Google BottomNavigation height

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add google bottom navigation to my android project. But I have a height problem with the bottom bar. How can I solve the problem? I tried it on devices with different resolutions. The result is the same.But everything is normal in the emulator

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1yuF.png)

[Test Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFFRj.jpg)

My code:

Main_activity.xml;

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_background"
            app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
            android:id="@+id/bottomnavigation"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

bottom_menu.xml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/homepage"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/fav_dolu"
        android:title="Search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_like"
        android:icon="@drawable/credits"

        android:title="Like" />



</menu>
```

I valued the height of Navigation Battombar and framelayout but the result did not change.